# System won't suspend after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, suspend, 14.04

Few days ago I upgraded my Linux machine to Ubuntu 14.04. After that, I notice that Ubuntu won't suspend anymore. Suspend works fine in 13.10. When I execute "Suspend" either from menu or from terminal with `sudo pm-suspend` the screen gets black with the following lines:

```
[  445.032801] PM: Syncing filesystems … done.
[  445.057818] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[  445.058006] Freezing user space processes --- (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  445.059860] Freezing remaining freezable tasks … (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  445.061194] PM: Entering mem sleep
[  445.061247] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using drive encryption?

Comment: No, I do not use drive encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem updating 13.10 server to 14.04.

Did you do a grub update after updating? I had a parameter in my grub that was "usbcore.autosuspend=-1"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash xbmc=autostart,noredir usbcore.autosuspend=-1"

And somehow the grub wasnt updated even though nothing was changed. After doing a  sudo update-grub it suspended fine.

Comment: The problem still persist in Ubuntu 15.04. But I find a "pattern": computer freeze on every 4th suspend. Any idea?