# After returning from suspend the keyboard and mouse doesn't respond

Tags: suspend

I have 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron-3537.
After resuming from suspend it takes me to log-in screen, and I'm unable to move cursor and no hotkeys are working nor "ctrl+alt+<kbd>f1</kbd>".
I tried sudo pm-suspend and after resuming it takes me to my desktop and this time I'm able to move my cursor but again nothing won't work.
Graphic drivers are installed.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You should try debugging your kernel (installing 12.04, 14.04 and mainline kernels) to verify where the problem resides. There's a nice guide in the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Comment: Recently I installed ubuntu 14.04.1, and suspend was working until first updates, i tried switching my graphic driver from fglrx to xserver-xorg but it didn't work. I followed the steps in wiki.ubuntu: note that command "dmesg > dmesg.txt" didn't work, so i just used "dmesg" and got this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8394298/ 
line 19 says "GHES: HEST is not enabled", i tried to find what does that mean but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yeah, if it break because the update you should definitively report that as bug. You could try to downgrade the packages one by one to find out which package broke your system, but sadly that's the most we can do.

Comment: I installed synaptic package manager and downgraded "pm-utilis", suspend works now but when resuming i get some errors on black screen before it takes me to log in screen. Here is a link for a picture of that errors. 
http://i61.tinypic.com/30m74nr.jpg

Comment: Yep, definitively a bug.

Comment: Now i tried to report that bug, and after writing in terminal "ubuntu-bug pm-utilis" after collecting information, it says "The problem cannot be reported : The report belongs to a package that is not installed."

Comment: Because the package causing problems isn't `pm-utils` *"This package provides simple shell command line tools to suspend and
 hibernate your computer."* Those scripts aren't the culprit, your kernel or xorg are. Check the link I pasted at the start about debugging suspend problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, I am assuming you are using a kernel newer than 3.12. 
It happened to me after the kernel upgrade. The solution is to try another kernel. 
Mine was fixed by downgrading to 3.12. LP told me it may be fixed if I upgrade to 3.15, but i did not try that.

Comment: isn't there a better solution than downgrading the kernel? everytime you run apt-get upgrade there's a chance for the kernel to be upgraded and therefore, messing up what you fixed, it's not very practical, linux is meant to be always updated

Comment: I totally agree with you, but if you are satisfied with a kernel version, you can lock the version from the software center to make not upgradeable. IMO as long as the kernel works fine for my machine I would upgrade the kernel manually  every four or five months. It is not like security or software update.

Comment: Can you tell me exact version of your downgraded kernel. I tried with 3.12.14 and with 3.15-RC4, both didn't work. I had some problems with 3.15, I installed it using steps form this link "http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/05/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-15-rc4-in-linux.html", there is also the step how to uninstal it and i did. But after i ran "uname-r" it tells me "3.15.0-031500rc4-generic", If you know how to completely remove it. I can also see this kernel in advanced settings when booting. I had to go there to chose 3.13 after suspend freeze with 3.15, it just did't wanted to boot later

Comment: sure, my kernel is 3.12.5-031205-generic from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.5-trusty/
If you want to uninstall a kernel, you can do so by searching within the package manager, its easier to browse kernels installed there. After that you will still see the version you are using even if you have removed it by "uname -a" until u actually reboot.

Comment: I tried with exact same version but resuming after suspend still freezes my computer. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Sorry it did not work. I hope someone else help.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login to your account, then enter:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

...then reboot. The problem will be solved.

Comment: no I always use those drivers and I have a suspend problem, once it goes to suspend, it freezes so your answer is wrong, or at the very least, doesn't always work

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly seeing this bug: [Black screen after login from suspend in Xubuntu 14.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736). Try removing `light-locker` and `light-locker-settings` and installing `xscreensaver` to solve the issue of buggy suspend/resume.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/455003/280643)

Comment: I'm not seeing the black screen, i get to the log in screen, or to the desktop if i enter 'pm-suspend' when suspending.
As i can remember from my old computer I should be able to get out of suspend by pressing space on keyboard (that was using ubutnu 13.10). Now I can only get out by pressing the power button.