# suspend error on 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, power-management, suspend

I've looked around and seems like various problems around suspend are wide spreaded for 14.04 release, nevertheless I haven't seen exactly my problem reported, nor my laptop model mentioned.

So, the problem. 
When I press sleep button system seems to be going into suspend, i.e. screen goes black, it stops responding on the keyboard and wireless LEDs turn off, however the power LED doesn't go into suspend state and CPU fan also keeps spinning. But unlike the other problem described here 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1315435
when I close the lid and reopen it - system wakes up and goes back to normal locked screen state, so reboot is not needed.

System details:
This is a clean freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04, 32bit
Laptop Dell D630
kernel 3.13.0-34-generic

Comment: I've had problems with suspend on a couple computers of mine since 8.04, they would kind of wake up but the graphics would be completely messed up.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the solution, this answer helped me https://askubuntu.com/a/461978/104548.

basically what you need to do is run this

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

and reboot.