# HP Pavilion G6 Won't Suspend with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, power-management, suspend, hp-pavilion

My HP Pavilion g6-2268ca with Ubuntu 14.04 won't suspend.  when the lid shuts the fan never cuts off.  i've checked my settings under power management and everything looks good.  when I manually click suspend, the screen goes dark for a second and then pops back up.
Originally the computer's screen would stay black after the lid was closed, so i followed the directions here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290 to fix that.  but now when i close the lid, fan continues, if the power cord is not installed, the battery will die.  if the cord is installed, the computer will be pretty hot because it isn't suspending.

also after making the changes suggested here:  [suspend is not working after updating to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453372/suspend-is-not-working-after-updating-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-13-10)
I now start the computer and i get the following error: "could not apply stored configuration for monitors Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element (e.g. )"

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to an upstream kernel, I'm on 3.15rc2 on trusty and it's working now where it wasn't before.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds